# Combine animate.css with waypoints

Tags: jquery, html, animation, jquery-waypoints, animate.css

I've been trying to combine animate.css with waypoints, and I cannot get the animations to work. Animate.css creates the animations, but they all happen on page load. I want the animations to happen when the element enters the screen, so that is why I am using waypoints.

I have loaded the animate and waypoints files into my site, and I'm linking to them. When I load my page, I see that my text disappears (opacity gets set to 0), but the animations don't appear as I scroll. Help please!

In my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Webartifacts/animate.css-master/animate.min.css">

<script src="../../Webartifacts/imakewebthings-waypoints-34d9f6d/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){

  // hide our element on page load
  $('#animateheader').css('opacity', 0);

  $('#animateheader').waypoint(function() {
      $('#animateheader').addClass('fadeInUp');
  }, { offset: '70%' });

});
</script>
```

The div that I want animated:

```
<div class="container animated" id="animateheader" style="margin-top:2%;margin-bottom:2%">
            <center>
                <font face="arial" color="#009fdb" size="+3">You + small changes = big change over time.</font><br><br>
                <font face="arial" color="#009fdb" size="+2">Your weekly dose of leadership, strategy, and personal development tips.<br><br>
                <font>
            </center>   
 </div><!--end container-->
```

I used this website to create this: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/05/31/scroll-anmiation-css-waypoints/

Comment: I'm guessing there's something wrong w/ the path to the script and/or css file because your code seems to work fine for me:  http://codepen.io/imjosh/pen/GWwLmx?editors=1111

I'm loading the waypoints.js and animate.css from a CDN. I'd recommend you do the same or change your relative paths to absolute ones

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/05/31/scroll-anmiation-css-waypoints/), it's just about combining Waypoints with animate.css

Answer (score 0):

**Waypoints with animate.css**

just add a class "fade-in-right" to which you want to add animations to multiple elements

```
$('.fade-in-right').css('opacity', 0);
$('.fade-in-right').waypoint(function() {
    $('.fade-in-right').addClass('fadeInRight');
}, { offset: '70%' });

$('.fade-in-left').css('opacity', 0);
$('.fade-in-left').waypoint(function() {
    $('.fade-in-left').addClass('fadeInLeft');
}, { offset: '70%' });

$('.fade-in-up').css('opacity', 0);
$('.fade-in-up').waypoint(function() {
    $('.fade-in-up').addClass('fadeInUp');
}, { offset: '70%' });

$('.fade-in-up').css('opacity', 0);
$('.fade-in-up').waypoint(function() {
    $('.fade-in-up').addClass('fadeInUp');
}, { offset: '70%' });
```